# Retain data on browser refresh in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-rest

I am working in `AngularJS` application with `Spring rest` as backend. I am pretty new to `angularjs`.

I have a UI page where i display some list of objects in table.There is an edit button against every record.When i click edit, another page opens which set the data accordingly.

The issue is, being on edit page, if I `refresh the browser`, I loss my data. One way I can think is to make another `rest` call but I want to avoid making any rest call.

Is there any way to retain data on the page on refresh or making rest call is better solution?

Comment: If the data you want to retain is relatively simple (an id, for example), you can try saving it in the url using [$location.search](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: not only id, there is whole object that should be displayed on page

Answer (score 1):

I would think the cleanest way to do it is to make a REST call, as the data could have changed on the server. However, if you want to avoid the call anyway, you may use `localstorage`. Just store the data in your table in localstore with key value pairs (assign some unique key to every row). You could use this plugin: [Angular LocalStorage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

Comment: Thanks!!..but why making the REST call would be the cleanest way? Suppose I have some value 'x' on the page before editing and when I refresh the page, due to REST call again, it could become 'y' as other user might have updated the value. So, it could be confusing to user...Does it make sense?

Comment: You mean the value y has been edited by user to x ? In such, case the user perhaps wants the latest value from server and hence is pressing refresh? If the value has been changed from x to y by somebody else on another client, is it not better that you show user a non-stale value?

Comment: but on read only screen i.e. before edit is clicked..the user saw value x and he decided to change the value to y so he clicked edit and navigated to edit screen...there he changed the value from x to y but before he could submit, he refresh the browser..if in between some other user has updated the value to y, he would be confused how did it become y even though he didn't update it..